# How to show only description part of Twilio error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, twilio-api

In Twilio error response we have error code and website address as a string. I need to show the only description part of the error to the user, not the whole error. how to do it in my rails app?

```
begin
  client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(
      Rails.application.credentials.twilio[:sid],
      Rails.application.credentials.twilio[:token]
  )
  client.messages.create(
      from: Rails.application.credentials.twilio[:number],
      to: "+#{account.country_code}#{account.phone_number}",
      body: "#{before} #{verification_code} #{after}"
  )
rescue Twilio::REST::TwilioError => e
  puts  e
  puts e.message
  return errors.add(:message, e.message) if e.message

end
```

this code is giving me error in this format:

Message [HTTP 400] 21211 : Unable to create record\nThe 'To' number +XXXXXXX is not a valid phone number.\nhttps://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21211\n\n

what I am looking for is this:

Unable to create record\nThe 'To' number +XXXXXXX is not a valid phone number.

Comment: Maybe, you can try `e.inspect` and then you can understand what this response contains? Anyway, the documentation says this object should contain an error message: https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/troubleshooting/debugging-your-application#debugging-calls-to-the-rest-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Error messages from the API that are exposed in the library are intended for developers and not end users. I wouldn't rely on them to be a good experience for your users.

Instead, I would recommend that you check the errors that you may receive, like the 21211 error example you are working with here, and write your own error messages for them. Then you should check against the error's `code` to get the right error. This will work better if you ever come to localise your application too.

Example:

```
TWILIO_ERROR_MESSAGES = {
  "21211" => "The number you are sending the message to does not appear to be valid."
}

begin
  client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(
      Rails.application.credentials.twilio[:sid],
      Rails.application.credentials.twilio[:token]
  )
  client.messages.create(
      from: Rails.application.credentials.twilio[:number],
      to: "+#{account.country_code}#{account.phone_number}",
      body: "#{before} #{verification_code} #{after}"
  )
rescue Twilio::REST::TwilioError => e
  message = TWILIO_ERROR_MESSAGES[e.code]
  return errors.add(:message, message)
end
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

see https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/blob/08f1ba2f042eeefb29f19f7dd13add40c4117ac9/lib/twilio-ruby/framework/error.rb#L39

All you have to do is write your owner error method, like

```
error_message = "#{e.error_message}\n#{e.detail}\n#{e.more_info}" 
errors.add(:message, error_message)
```